# How to read WMDRM 10 KEYID from file

Tags: drm

I wanted to if it is possible to read a KeyID from an encrypted file using WMDRM 10?
Of course it is a clear text somehow, but is it possible? how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy answer is that you can binary-parse the file and look for the `<WMRMHEADER>` tag and the `<KID>` tag within it (both Unicode-encoded). The key ID is within the `<KID>` tag.

The correct (but much harder) way is to use Windows Media Format 11 SDK and the `IWMDRMReader::GetDRMProperty()` method with the `g_wszWMDRM_DRMHeader_KeyID` constant. However, you are gonna need WMDRM "stub libs" from Microsoft in order to do that (i.e. be a DRM licensee).

Answer (score 1):

Using the WMF SDK is preferred, but another option is to implement ASF Parsing.  The spec is available @ http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14995 and there are various implementations of ASF Parsers in different languages.